# SharePoint search administration - search results page error

Tags: search, sharepoint, reporting

In my SharePoint 2007 development environment in Central Administration Shared Services > Search administration> Search Results Report page I am getting "An unexpected error has occurred" message instead of actual search results.  In my production environment I do see results.  To get better error message I changed web.config  file: `callstack = true`, `customerrors = Off` `and debug = true` with no change.

I have also configured site usage reporting by enabling usage logging and usage reporting and activated report feature all to no avail.  Doe anyone know what might be the problem?  I must be missing something.  (I did IIS reset after changing web.config file).

Comment: 7/25/11..following up my previous post - I solved this problem a while back by doing a number of things the first was to install PDFiFilter65installer to enable PDF file type content to be searched which they were not doing at the time. Then I added scopes and created crawler impact rules and ran full crawl. Basically my server was not configured for searching and I had to learn how to set it up!

Comment: It's great that you found a solution. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @hammar - I wasn't sure it was kosher to answer my own post so I edited it instead but I followed your advice and answered it anyway!  Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

7/25/11..following up my previous post - I solved this problem a while back by doing a number of things the first was to install PDFiFilter65installer to enable PDF file type content to be searched which they were not doing at the time. Then I added scopes and created crawler impact rules and ran full crawl. Basically my server was not configured for searching and I had to learn how to set it up!